# Finding original amount in half-life problem

Tags: logarithms

Say the half-life of an element is 1590 years. If 10g of the element is left after 1000 years, how much was there originally?

Comment: What do you know about this kind of problem? Have you not been shown some formulas that might be useful?

Comment: I know how to calculate half-life but don't know how to find the original amount.

Comment: So, how do you calculate half-life?

Comment: ln(fraction remaining) = -kt

Comment: What does $k$ stand for? what does $t$ stand for? How would you use that formula? what would you have to know, and what computation would you do? Full sentences, please.

Comment: k stands for rate constant and t for time. to use the formula you would need to know at least 2 of the 3 unknowns.

Comment: The amount of the element has halved $\frac{1000}{1590}$ times. There was $\displaystyle 2^{\frac{1000}{1590}}\times 10g$ initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$\text{Amount remaining} =\text{Original Amount} \times \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\text{number of half lives}} $$

solve for $X$ in the equation

$$10 = X \times \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1000}{1590}}$$